# Associating Things

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm creating a football database and I created two scaffolds: one called Clubs, that has some basic information (Name and Stadium, both strings), and another called Players. The players have names, and nationalities. Here are both of the models:

```
class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :nationality
  belongs_to :club
end

class Club < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :stadium
  has_many :players
end
```

I'm wondering what the next step is. I created and have a list of clubs, but I want to be able to add a club to a player by editing the player, or when creating a new player. Then going into clubs and seeing a list of players assigned to that club.

Comment: You have, of course, `club_id` column in your `players` table?

Comment: All you need is here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

Answer (score 0):

you need to add a foreign key 'club_id' to payer to Player model, and in player new/edit form add a select tag to list clubs.

and in clubs's new/edit form add a multiselect box for player to be added/removed to club.

instead of multiselect box you can use jquery token.

http://railscasts.com/episodes/258-token-fields